# Angular2 xdomain IE9

Tags: angular, cross-domain, internet-explorer-9

I've followed the basic app instructions: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

I'm trying to get cross domain http requests on IE9 to go through and saw alot of non-angular solutions referring to xdomain: https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain

I'm struggling (adding different shims) trying to get xdomain to work with Angular2. Is there something I'm missing here?

Error I'm seeing: More tasks executed then were scheduled

Below is my index.html setup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->

    <!--[if lte IE 9]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
          'use strict';
          // IE9 Console Bug Fix
          window.console = window.console || {};
          window.console.log = window.console.log || function() {};
      </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xdomain/0.7.5/xdomain.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="_xdomainVariables.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->


    <script src="node_modules/ie-shim/dist/browser.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2-ie9-shims/shims_for_IE.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>



    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you get this working?  I'm getting the same error with IE9 and xdomain.

Comment: nope but had to implement a reverse proxy for IE9 using https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-web-server